# C# Using Reflection list only top classes excluding linked ones

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a rather simple collection of many (too many..) classes in a specific namespace. They have no nested classes, but the do have linked ones. Example (simplified):

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Methods
{
    public class Method100Response201
    {

        public Method100Response201()
        {
            super = new Method100Response201_1();
        }

        public string aName { get; set; }
        public string R1_201 { get; set; } = "R1_201";
        public Method100Response201_1 super { get; set; }

        public void DoSpecialThing()
        {
             Console.WriteLine ("Something Blue.."); //just complimentary-no use
        }

    }

    public class Method100Response201_1
    {
        public string aName { get; set; }
        public string R1_201_1 { get; set; } = "R1_201_1";
    }

    public class Method100Response404
    {
        public void DoSpecialThing()
        {
          Console.WriteLine ("Something Old.."); 
        }

        public string R1_04 { get; set; } = "R1_04";
    }

    public class Method200Response200
    {
        public string R2_02 { get; set; } = "R2_02";
    }
}
```

This is what I have (consider that all my classes are in "ConsoleApp1.Methods"):

```
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly (), "ConsoleApp1.Methods");

for ( int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++ )
{
      Console.WriteLine ("Found Response Model: "+ typelist[i].Name);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

having

```
private static Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                   .ToArray();
}
```

How could I transform my code so that I get a list of ***only*** the top classes (*consider as top classes those not present as types of properties of other classes*)

**Expected results**

```
Method100Response201
Method100Response404
Method200Response200
```

not the `Method100Response201_1` because is used by `Method100Response201`

Comment: Can you tidy the code thanks, this is hard to read

Comment: Also you have 3 questions here, 1) To get a list of classes, 2) get a list of types of properties of those classes, 3) return a list where of classes which are not in the other list.

Comment: @Michael Randall Thank you for looking it up, I will format better the code asap. As for your points, is just one point, just the list of the top classes (as long as they are not referenced as types of properties in other classes).

Comment: Which is step 3) and the easier step

Comment: @Michael Randall: I tied up ten seconds after your first post, you may check.

Comment: ahh good so you did

Comment: @MichaelRandall I don't know what exactly should I do when you mention "tied up", I edited the margins and the lineup of the code, then deleted some irrelevant to the question, and at the end added the Type[] that I use and forgot to include. Anyhow, thank you for your feedback....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```
var classes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                       .Where(t => 
                                 t.IsClass && 
                                 t.Namespace == "ConsoleApp1.Methods" && 
                                 !t.IsNested)
                       .ToList();

var properties = classes.SelectMany(
   x => x.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .Select(y => y.PropertyType));

var results = classes.Where(x => !properties.Contains(x))
                     .Select(x => x.Name);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Given your exact namespace, the results are

```
Method100Response201
Method100Response404
Method200Response200
```

<sub>***Note*** : i made some assumptions here, however tweak this code as you need</sub>

Comment: It seems correct, but i don't know how to iterate through the results; I converted ToArray() and tried to loop through but just prints System.Type.

Comment: @Nick do you just want the names?

Comment: i do `results.ForEach (Console.WriteLine);` but apparently I am wrong, I only get results System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.String] and `foreach ( string item in results ) { Console.WriteLine(item); }` gives the same - your advice? I am doing something wrong..
Even worst, I can't manage it (apologies, a line of code was running trying to console print "results") I got nothing

Comment: @nick updated again.., with the for each and the results i get

Comment: YES ! THANK YOU ! Life saver.. I tested it with a separate .cs file with a group of 400+ classes: 100% match. impressive, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do that then you’ve got some work to do. Put the types in a hashset, Loop through all the types and get all the properties, look at the return types of the properties, remove those types from the hash set. Nothing magical about it.

Comment: Thank you indeed for looking this up. I thought to make an inner loop and list the properties types, but I don't know how to check if their type is "generic" or another class.. if I could manage that, I could exclude the method from the outer (current) loop..

Comment: The Type object contains information about whether or not the type is generic. For example the documentation for IsGenericType says "Use the IsGenericType property to determine whether a Type object represents a generic type. Use the ContainsGenericParameters property to determine whether a Type object represents an open constructed type or a closed constructed type."